# Issue with the jquerymodal.com control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make use of the really cool Jquery Modal framework, which can be found [here](http://jquerymodal.com/). I've done the first step and nothing happens. Maybe I'm just stupid, but the jquerymodal.com site says it's as easy as the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</style>
  <!-- Don't forget to include jQuery ;) -->
  <script src="jquery.modal.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Modal HTML embedded directly into document -->
  <div id="ex1" style="display:none;">
    <p>Thanks for clicking.  That felt good.  <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a> or press ESC</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Link to open the modal -->
  <p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open Modal</a></p>

</body>
```

When I launch my HTML page and click the "Open Modal" link, it does nothing. Nothing happens in any browser. Even if I host it in IIS and run it from VS as an admin. And yes, of course, I have placed the JqueryModal js and project zip files into the same directory as my HTML file. But, that said... there's no WAY the developer of this framework was negligent enough to publish his files without testing them. So what in the world am I doing wrong??? Can someone please slap me in the face and spell it out for me?

Answer (score 0):

The below works fine for me. I included jQuery library and the CSS file for jQuery modal to make it work.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.8.2/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.8.2/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<!-- Modal HTML embedded directly into document -->
<div id="ex1" style="display:none;">
  <p>Thanks for clicking. That felt good. <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a> or press ESC</p>
</div>

<!-- Link to open the modal -->
<p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open Modal</a></p>
```

Comment: Sure, that works, but your src urls are all pointing to somplace elsewhere. Like cdnjs.cloudflare.com. I want my libraries to be local. That's why I downloaded the Jquery Modal library. I included a link to the download page on my first post. Can someone please download the library using the link I provided and tell me what I've done wrong? I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Now I see the comment in the sample code "Don't forget to include jquery". LOL. I blew it :)